# Identifying the Milky Way uniquely

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, galaxies, milky-way

Let’s suppose you wanted to elegantly represent the Milky Way in a minimalist fashion in a way that would make sense a billion years hence (ie let’s set aside the damage wrought by colliding with Andromeda etc)

Are the objects with simple orbits that are observable at extreme distances and long lived enough to serve the purpose?

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The [Sun orbits the galaxy in a rough period of about 230 million years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_year).  Over a billion years there's no practical way to represent our position (or indeed know what it would be now).

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine: you misunderstood the question. I'm not trying to represent the location of the Solar System (and the fact it orbits the galaxy is explicit in the original question) but the galaxy itself. E.g. is there some unique identifying set of objects in the galaxy whose relationship and longevity is sufficient to identify the Milky Way?

Comment: @Qmechanic yes, you're probably right.